# Convert output to JSON using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to convert this kind of output:

```
samaccountname: displayname
samaccountname2: displayname2
```

to something like this:

```
{
"samaccountname": "displayname",
"samaccountname2": "displayname2"
}
```

Could you please give me a hand?

Thanks!

BTW, this is the output of an LDAP Search Query, so it needs to work receiving the data from pipe / stdin.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? (Using raw input, and regex support, are both covered in jq's documentation; if we know where you're stuck, we can write a better answer).

Comment: ...that said, I strongly suggest using something like [`ldap2json`](https://github.com/larsks/ldap2json) rather than reinventing this wheel. LDAP results have a lot of different escaping modes, so there's a lot more than just splitting on the first `:` required to cover the format correctly. jq is a capable tool -- it *can* do base64 decoding and most of the other transformations required -- but it's a lot of work to test all the corner cases, and makes a lot of sense to use a 3rd-party tool where that work has been done for you.

Comment: hey! Thanks for your quick reply.
I need to update certain data from the ldapquery.. I cannot install anything on the server that is running the script I am creating, there's only JQ.

The ldapquery is completely done and it will give me always the same output I put on the first comment. Just need to get it in JSON to upload this data to another system.

Comment: Be sure you test with names that can contain non-English characters, if they're possible -- that's one of the scenarios where instead of `samaccountname: displayname` you might get `samaccountname:: ZGlzcGxheW5hbWUK` (that's the literal base64 encoding of "displayname"). If you don't have an enforced limit on how long your display names are, it's also possible for them to wrap over multiple lines.

Comment: ...personally, back when I ran an LDAP site, I made heavy use of the noninteractive usage modes for [`ldapvi`](http://www.lichteblau.com/ldapvi/manual/); the format it converts LDAP records to/from is more consistent, and consequently easier to script.

Answer (score 4):

**If** you can parse based on the first colon, this will do it:

```
jq -Rn '[inputs | capture("(?<key>[^:]*): *(?<value>.*)")] | from_entries'
```

You might want to add a filter to do further trimming.  (jq has `ltrimstr` and `rtrimstr` in case that helps.)

### regex-free

Or (apart from the trimming):

```
jq -Rn '[inputs | index(":") as $i | {key: .[:$i], value: .[1+$i:]}] | from_entries'
```

### ldapsearch

ldapsearch has an option:

> -B
>
> Do not suppress display of non-ASCII values.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using ldapsearch with nowrap, you can use:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -E pr=1000/noprompt -o ldif-wrap=no <put your stuff here> |
jq --slurp --raw-input 'split("\n\n")|map(split("\n")|map(select(.[0:1]!="#" and length>0)) |select(length > 0)|map(capture("^(?<key>[^:]*:?): *(?<value>.*)") |if .key[-1:.key|length] == ":" then .key=.key[0:-1]|.value=(.value|@base64d) else . end)| group_by(.key) | map({key:.[0].key,value:[.[].value]})| from_entries)'
```

Explaining:

```
# Split entries by empty new lines
split("\n\n")|
# for each entry
map(
  # split attribute on each entry
  split("\n")|
  # drop comments and empty lines
  map(select(.[0:1]!="#" and length>0)) |
  # and empty arrays
  select(length > 0) |
  # for each attribute
  map(
    # Capture key and value, keeping a trailing ":" for base64 
    capture("^(?<key>[^:]*:?): *(?<value>.*)") |
    # for those base64, decode the value and chomp the extra ":"
    if .key[-1:.key|length] == ":" then .key=.key[0:-1]|.value=(.value|@base64d) else . end
  )|
 # Now group repeated attributes by attribute name
 group_by(.key) |
 # And join values
 map({key:.[0].key,value:[.[].value]})|
 # Finally, convert key/values to json
 from_entries
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done without "from_entries" function:

```
jq -Rn '[ inputs |split(": ") |{ (.[0]):.[1] } ] |add'
```